# From match results to rating using Trueskill (in Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, rating, rating-system

I'm trying to use Trueskill in Python, specifically this library: http://trueskill.org/, to generate rating from match results.

However, I didn't see obvious way to do this. From the document on the site, given two ratings, one can simulate the rating updated via `rate_1vs1`. But I didn't the other way around, that is, given match results and generate ratings for all the players.

Any hints on this? Or should I use another implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in fact `rate_1vs1` is the way to go. By looking at the source code I think the assumption is that the first argument is the winner. i.e.,

```
# if alice win
alice, bob = rate_1vs1(alice, bob)
# if bob win
bob, alice = rate_1vs1(bob, alice)
# if drawn
alice, bob = rate_1vs1(alice, bob, drawn=True)  # order doesn't matter in this case
```